# Проблема с разметкой item для ListView

Tags: android

Пытаюсь сделать свой item для listview. Вот код разметки

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imgRadio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRadio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Радиостанция"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

в студии видно нормально, а в вирт устройстве, когда запускаю, совсем иначе отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а должно быть так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Картинке разрешили занять место в соответствии с размером. Она этой возможностью воспользовалась. Либо променяйте картинку, либо явно задайте ее размеры (второе предпочтительней).

Comment: понял. спасибо.

Comment: Автор ответа, а что лучше? `adjustViewBounds` или `scaleType`

Comment: @СергейГрушин эти константы про разное. adjustViewBounds даст  возможность ImageView в процессе измерения занять место с тем же соотношением сторон, что и расположенная внутри картинка. scaleType же - это то, как преобразовывать картинку для показа внутри ImageView, на размер ImageView оно не влияет. Для описанной задачи я бы использовал точно заданные размеры в layout'е и scaleType со значением centerCrop или centerInside.

Comment: @СергейГрушин если сможете, то почитайте, как у ImageView работает onMeasure(), многое станет понятней. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java

Comment: Ага, СПС)) А вот смотрите если я хочу сделать  `ImageView` квадратным, причём сторона этого квадрата неизвестна (вычисляется по весу) как быть?

Comment: @СергейГрушин про квадратные вью лучше задать отдельный вопрос, это часто встречающаяся интересная задача.